# Macedonian keyboard in Lubuntu 14.10?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, language-support

I've been trying to install Macedonian (MKD) keyboard on Lubuntu but it's not listed. 
Is there any way that I somehow get it or download it or is it just not supported yet?

(new to Linux, be nice :D )

Comment: Strange, it is supported in Ubuntu 14.10 under `system settings/text entry`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have the language pack installed, right click the flag or two letter code (which indicates the country).  Choose "keyboard layout handler" settings.  Uncheck Keep system layouts and the select Add.  Scroll down to Macedonian (mk) and select it and then OK.  You can then move it up or leave it where it is. Recheck Keep system layouts. Close.  I believe that you have to reboot for the changes to take effect.

Comment: just noticed that it's lubuntu 14.10 and not 14.04 -.- if that makes any difference. macedonian is still not listed.